# How can I fetch the source of a Web page in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, http

I'm fetching Web page source with IdHTTP Indy component, but after reading about a problem with it and some questions on this Web site, it seems that it's not always the best choice.

What are your suggestions for fetching Web pages?

Comment: which issues do you have using indy to do this task?

Comment: There are no problems with the Indd IdHTTP client. I built an entire system for downloading sporting results from the web from many different sites and never had any issues at all. I think you may have been misinformed.

Comment: @Misha, I don't know what is wrong with Google Search API except it is deprecated and it will in 3 years be shutted down. Well, if you, Danijel, really believe that Google will serve you the same data in the iFrame which is unaccessible for you by using simple HTTP GET reqest then I can't help you even if I wanted to ;)

Comment: What problems do you have? If you're basing your non-question on something you read somewhere, you're not going to get far. If you want help, you need to post actual questions, and stop saying things like "thanks for neg. rep". Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you have an idea of how this site works and what constitutes an actual question. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yeah, answers to your previous question were kinda... questionable, but complaining about that only makes users more angry. Anyway, `TIdHttp` usage is quite straightforward, got any specific problems to resolve?

Comment: -1 The Question is unspecific and not useful. You do not have a problem at all.

Comment: I need to fetch very long link , but problem is 255 characters limit, what about that , and wininet I tried it ,but sometimes on win7 while fetching webpage it stops responding :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Indy. Create a `TIdHTTP` object and call its `Get` method. It returns the Web page source as a string, or places it in a stream that you provide.

Comment: Be sure to implement a redirect handler though.

Comment: @Marco, set HandleRedirects to True

Answer (score 2):

With COM/ActiveX objects, WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1:

```
function getPostTranslateLibre3(feedstream, fromlang, tolang: string): string;
var
  Url,aAPI_KEY, source: string;
  jo, locate: TJSONObject;
  httpReq,hr: Olevariant;
  strm: TStringStream;
begin
  httpReq:= CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  // Open the HTTPs connection.  
  try              
    hr:= httpReq.Open('POST','https://libretranslate.pussthecat.org/translate', false);
    httpReq.setRequestheader('user-agent',CUSERAGENT  );
    httpReq.setRequestheader('content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  
             
    if hr= S_OK then HttpReq.Send('q='+HTTPEncode(feedstream)+
                                  '&source='+fromlang+'&target='+tolang);
    If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
       result:= HttpReq.responseText
    Else result:= 'Failed at getting response:'+itoa(HttpReq.Status)+HttpReq.responseText;
    //writeln('debug response '+HttpReq.GetAllResponseHeaders);     
  finally
    httpreq:= unassigned;  
  end;                  
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is calling the WinInet functions, which is doable but a lot of work.
If you already use COM/ActiveX objects, you could consider using MSXML2's XmlHttpRequest or the WinInet component: see here for an example http://yoy.be/item.asp?i142

Or if you want to show the web-page on screen, you could use the TWebBrowser component: http://yoy.be/item.asp?i598