# How to download a web page into a variable?

Tags: delphi

I don't care whether it is a string, stringlist, memo, etc ... but not a disk file

How do I download a compete web page into a variable?  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fetch the source of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800026/how-can-i-fetch-the-source-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using Indy:

```
uses IdHTTP;

const
  HTTP_RESPONSE_OK = 200;

function GetPage(aURL: string): string;
var
  Response: TStringStream;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Result := '';
  Response := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      HTTP.Get(aURL, Response);
      if HTTP.ResponseCode = HTTP_RESPONSE_OK then begin
        Result := Response.DataString;
      end else begin
        // TODO -cLogging: add some logging
      end;
    finally
      HTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Response.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 BUT, what do I need in "uses" to get at HTTP_RESPONSE_OK ?

Comment: @MarjanVenema, Is there a reason why you use `TStringStream`? why not simply: `Result := HTTP.Get(URL)`

Comment: @kobik: Oh, that's just because it is a stripped version of actual code and in that code I use the stream to find specific stuff.

Comment: @Mawg: Sorry, that's one of my own constants. It's value is 200 (an Integer). Updated answer with it.

Comment: Indy beats WinInet here because WinInet has glitches including the dread timeout bug.   WinInet can be handy in case you need to do something really weird with proxies.  WinHttp would be another alternative.

Comment: @DoctorLai: have you set up Indy to use the OpenSSL libraries? You need those to make anything regarding HTTPS work.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand 's solution doesn't need SSL libraries and it works for HTTPS using WinInet API

Comment: @DoctorLai: well, no of course not. His solution doesn't use Indy... Apparently I should have spelled out that "anything regarding HTTPS" was meant within the parameters of the solution offered: using Indy.

Answer (score 14):

Using the native Microsoft Windows WinInet API:

```
function WebGetData(const UserAgent: string; const URL: string): string;
var
  hInet: HINTERNET;
  hURL: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  BufferLen: cardinal;
begin
  result := '';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if hInet = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar(URL), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    if hURL = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      repeat
        if not InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen) then
          RaiseLastOSError;
        result := result + UTF8Decode(Copy(Buffer, 1, BufferLen))
      until BufferLen = 0;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;
```

Try it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Text := WebGetData('My Own Client', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk')
end;
```

But this only works if the encoding is UTF-8. So, to make it work in other cases, you either have to handle these separately, or you can use the Indy high-level wrappers, as suggested by Marjan. I admit they are superior in this case, but I still want to promote the underlying API, if for no other reason than educational...

Comment: LOL, sorry, corrected. My brain is getting foggy. Must be because I past 50 last Thursday.