# Delphi: How to get data from this website?

Tags: php, html, xml, web-services, delphi

I'm trying to get data from a website:

> `http://site2.aesa.pb.gov.br/aesa/monitoramentoPluviometria.do?metodo=listarMesesChuvasMensais` ([translated via Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.br/translate?sl=pt&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsite2.aesa.pb.gov.br%2Faesa%2FmonitoramentoPluviometria.do%3Fmetodo%3DlistarMesesChuvasMensais&edit-text=))

In Delphi I know working with XML based Webservices (SOAP, WSDL), but this site does not provide such kind of services.

But I do not have knowledge in languages ​​like PHP and HTML, not even web languages ​​in general.

My question is, is there any way to get data from that site with the knowledge I do (not) have? Is there a tool to do this in Delphi? What are the common first steps to study the ability to do this?

Input January and 2014:

http://site2.aesa.pb.gov.br/aesa/monitoramentoPluviometria.do?metodo=listarMesesChuvasMensais

Output:

a generic method url

http://site2.aesa.pb.gov.br/aesa/monitoramentoPluviometria.do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239267/how-to-download-a-web-page-into-a-variable

Comment: Delphi is probably the wrong tool for the job

Comment: It's just a static table which you can parse e.g. with MSHTML.

Comment: @TLama like in this  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348346/html-tag-parsing)?

Comment: Yup, similarly. But I'd prefer access through one of the `IHTMLTable` interfaces. Try to search something related to `IHTMLTable`.

Comment: Have you considered using the standard URLDownloadToFile() routine  and then parsing the file yourself?

Comment: @MartynA the problem is my [website](http://site2.aesa.pb.gov.br/aesa/monitoramentoPluviometria.do?metodo=listarMesesChuvasMensais) do not return nothing. I have to save page in html (using the Chrome) and after parsing the file. I'm trying follow the (at)mjn steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use a HTTP client such as Internet Direct (Indy) or Synapse to get the web page as text.
Then you can either a HTML parser library or plain string routines to extract the table data.

How to perform HTTP requests is shown in many articles and Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: after one day studying, you answer makes sense (for me), thanks.