# How to download a very simple HTTPS page in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, web, https, pascal

I tried a code I saw here but it didn't work for HTTPS. I need to download this page as a String, and add some Break lines on it to put the informations in order in a TMemo.

How to do it? I tried to use Indy but I failed because of the SSL.

I tried the solutions of this page: [How to download a web page into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239267/how-to-download-a-web-page-into-a-variable)

How to download this page https://api.rastrearpedidos.com.br/api/rastreio/v1?codigo=OP133496280BR thats just pure text and put in in a String? and also format it like that, in the lines of a TMemo:

```
"Objeto em trânsito - por favor aguarde"
"cidade":"SAO JOSE DOS CAMPOS"
"uf":"SP"
"dataHora":"18/06/2021 16:53"
"descricao":"Objeto postado","cidade":"SAO JOSE DOS CAMPOS","uf":"SP"
```

It's portuguese, English isn't my first language. Thanks if you guys could help me. I Use the Embarcadero Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: *it failed because of the SSL*. Of course it did, if you don't have SSL installed.   How else are you going to establish the encrypted session to download the page? Do you understand what HTTPS is, and how it's different from HTTP? As far as English not being your first language, there's [pt.so] available if you're more comfortable writing in Portugese.

Comment: How to install SSL to work properly?

Comment: Search this site for *Indy SSL*. It's been described here many times before.

Comment: "*I tried a code I saw here but it didn't work for HTTPS*" - what code EXACTLY did you use? Please be more specific. "*I tried to use Indy but I failed because of the SSL*" - assuming you are using the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component, then you likely did not have the OpenSSL DLLs in the same folder as your EXE, or you used the wrong version of the DLLs. What does Indy's `OpenSSLVersion()` and WhichFailedToLoad()` functions report after the failure occurred?

Comment: Looks like a [follow up to your collegue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68043376/4299358).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Indy, assuming you are using Indy's default `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component for SSL/TLS support, then make sure you put the 2 OpenSSL DLLs, `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`, in the same folder as your EXE.  You can get them from here:

https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries

Note that `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` only supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2.  If you need to use OpenSSL 1.1.x instead (for TLS 1.3+, etc), then [use this `SSLIOHandler`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead.  You will have to obtain the relevant OpenSSL DLLs from elsewhere, or compile them yourself.

Either way, once you decide which `SSLIOHandler` you want to use, the code is fairly simple:

```pascal
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Response: string;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    // configure HTTP as needed (version, headers, etc)...

    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
    // configure SSL as needed (TLS versions, certificates, etc)...
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;

    Response := HTTP.Get('https://api.rastrearpedidos.com.br/api/rastreio/v1?codigo=OP133496280BR');
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
  
  // use Response as needed...
end;
```

Comment: I'm interested in it too. Can you write a little code how to use it to download the page?

Comment: @VictorMelo As KenWhite wrote in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042321/?noredirect=1#comment120263017_68042321), there are *numerous* questions on StackOverflow that show how to use `TIdHTTP` with `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.  Do a search.

Comment: I downloaded everything, but I have no idea how to use it. Can someone please write a little example of how to download the text of the https://api.rastrearpedidos.com.br/api/rastreio/v1?codigo=OP133496280BR page and put it in a string? I'm trying to learn, and it's very hard.

Comment: @Adrianorox Seriously? <sigh> Fine, I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sorry for offtopic, are there any tutorial how to safely install latest indy from github? I need to use TLS 1.3 in one of projects and don't wan't to spend an evening trying to let it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Request: TScHttpWebRequest;
  Response: TScHttpWebResponse;
  ResponseStr: String;
  JSonValue: TJSonValue;
  JsonArray: TJsonArray;
  Name: String;
  UserName: String;
  Email: String;
begin
  Request := TScHttpWebRequest.Create('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  try
    Response := Request.GetResponse;    
    try
      if Request.IsSecure then begin
      ResponseStr := Response.ReadAsString;
      JsonArray := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(ResponseStr) as TJsonArray;
      try
        for i:=0 to JsonArray.Count - 1 do begin
          JsonValue := JsonArray.Items[i];
          Name := JsonValue.GetValue('name');
          UserName := JsonValue.GetValue('username');
          Email := JsonValue.GetValue('email');
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Name: ' + Name + ' - UserName: ' + UserName + ' - Email: ' + Email);
        end;
      finally
        JsonArray.Free;
      end;
      end;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Request.Free;
  end;
end;
```