# How to extract website Source code in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need a way to extract the website source code in Delphi and put it in a TStrings or TStringList

exactly the same way when you click on View Source in the Internet Explorer and it opens the notepad and shows the source code.

Maybe we can use TWebBrowser or I don't know
Thank you.

Comment: You can only view the html output, not the code that was server side.

Comment: simply use Indy IdHttp.Get(url)

Comment: Yeh all i need is the client side code which is an HTML I guess

Comment: which is usually a set of interconnected files. One or more HTML files. Zero or more CSS files. Zero or more JS files. Pictures, flashes, java applets...

To get single file - root HTML file of the page - any HTTP libray would work like INDY referenced above. However it may be all the code or only little fraction of it, highly depending on the site.

Comment: Thank you all for the help....the Indy thing works like charm...thanks @kobik

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fetch the source of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800026/how-can-i-fetch-the-source-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Indy you can simply do

```
Strings.Text := IdHttp.Get(URL);
```

You really don't want to spin up a TWebBrowser for a simple HTTP GET.